Related to Chinese Writing in the windows weather app and its related registry... as from 28 december 2024
it's to do with msn weather app that's built into windows, msn weather i think it's called...
when the  weather app is run, the writing is in Chinese... I checked my location settings etc on my computer... all set to uk… so I did a google search for the problem... came across a microsoft site in which a lot of people have had the same issue... all started on the 28th december 2024... See:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-weather-app-is-in-chinese/245f4880-df4f-4aa4-9108-c12182e49f6e?page=3 ..some people said they uninstalled the weather app, turned off their pc's, waited a few minutes and rebooted then reinstalled the app, worked for some people but not everyone, I did the same thing and it didn't work for me, so I did more investigating, someone posted an image of their windows registry (regedit), and found some Chinese writing in a couple of lines in their registry...
https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/5cc37470-4777-42d7-a744-2ced5b5d9e28?upload=true&fud_access=hC1SxZhn7m%2FZQJkOIiOVstu10yTQgXS4A%2FDBzZTg8nbaCgIogkrcDydMeI5Y4za2dOqDdWtsG2JNS3E35V60i9TiGHR7STMpJHheeXuDvO8nwjUlqCBHhJ0NDvuYN7OSnlLQhFHg82Vq3cijI4H8EPwvUcU6ccmFQuacb5PSXGqSQtWKHo%2F232Q%2BfBA1q8Zo%2F40vZSnvSyx7%2BHvwf7BcgP6LqFCTJwXRNDsg9aBeYduhLaPvFzAG39OqBa7PbAWW%2FlshtbU3kdeG2ys7RQ3hzOuKSgDc391ImBXnEwTpFTgANdSjSJzVurZ4TCmS8wYQ20APdz3KBfJrIrsyt9PkpB%2Bfzx%2B1vJZ0AXRUnAe0OTX%2FNEc7rTptXPfM57vDtiApXt%2B%2B8gcKBic84ANro9qTXWOArhd1mRo%2BnePn%2BVEhdIg%3D, so the registry shows:
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1232480833-3600853269-1034476866-1005\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\Backup\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy!App ,then: '(Default) REG_SZ Value not set', 'appType REG_SZ  app:immersive', 'channelCreation REG_SZ 133798982295479862' , 'channelExpiry REG_SZ 133824092290000000' , 'channelld REG_SZ 㬱㐷㔹㜸㌱㤲〳㄰〸㔶4' , 'channelUri REG_SZ 瑨灴㩳⼯湷㉳氭㉮⹰潮楴祦眮湩潤獷挮浯㼯潴敫㵮睁䅙䅁祃䍴㈥偦搳睩潄畹祊煡朰㈥癦䩁䕶爰灃㈥䥦䩸払卑㡳䉱䕤瑡す䕔伸扇㈥塦䭲㈥灢䱇稳婦奙䨹㈥坢灔䭇搹睮䥯獅削浔祰捐䍡╧昲丰╃戲䵭ㅑ祊䌸䙴前渵扂㈥畢捳╩昲歙湧╉戲稲㑯歚㡃獮㤲潆䕶㉧汖氰' , 'deviceVersion REG_SZ 1' , 'Setting REG_SZ c:badge,c:cloud,c:internet,c:ringing,c:tile,c:tickle,s:toast,s:audio,s:badge,s:banner,s:listenerEnabled,s:lock:toast,s:tile,s:voip' 
...i highlighted the Chinese writing in my registry then put it into google translator... this is where its very odd...
the first line: '㬱㐷㔹㜸㌱㤲〳㄰〸㔶4' came up with just '4' but when I removed the '4' and re- translated it, the translation read: 'The 2020 Beijing International Expo will be held on the 28th of this month. The 2020 Beijing International Expo will be held on the 28th of this month'
the second line: '瑨灴㩳⼯湷㉳氭㉮⹰潮楴祦眮湩潤獷挮浯㼯潴敫㵮睁䅙䅁祃䍴㈥偦搳睩潄畹祊煡朰㈥癦䩁䕶爰灃㈥䥦䩸払卑㡳䉱䕤瑡す䕔伸扇㈥塦䭲㈥灢䱇稳婦奙䨹㈥坢灔䭇搹睮䥯獅削浔祰捐䍡╧昲丰╃戲䵭ㅑ祊䌸䙴前渵扂㈥畢捳╩昲歙湧╉戲稲㑯歚㡃獮㤲潆䕶㉧汖氰' when put into the translator, read:

'The 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China, the 6th anniversary celebration of the founding of the People's Republic of China,''

...so very strange! I have uninstalled the msn weather app and replaced it with a different app, but I wonder if it's possible that Chinese hackers have done a dummy run hack on the Microsoft servers, and if so, is it possible that  a far more serious hack on Microsoft is coming in the future? one that will maybe affect every windows user? …it is well known that china and co are always trying to hack America and maybe the entire west..but hopefully it's nothing serious and i'm just a bit paranoid... however i would like to know if anyone knows the right registry settings for the weather app? the info i have is:
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1232480833-3600853269-1034476866-1005\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\Backup\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy!App
...if you could look at the registry info and  tell me what is meant to be there it would be very appreciated as i can get back to the microsoft forum and let others know how to fix the issue. also would it be best to delete the entire registry keys related to this issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

hi, to clarify... as described in the title, this is a problem with the windows weather app. with a link to the article at 'answers.microsoft.com' i have provided as much info as i can get right now, including all the research i have done. and as written i have included a link plus a written description of the registry values affected. and i have asked if anyone knows what the registry values should be. so i can not ask any other question to tell exactly what i am asking, i do not know any more information i can give, as i have given as much information about this as possible.

i have an idea... if someone is willing to open their windows registry to the location as shown and described in my question to see if they have the same issue, if they don't have the chinese writing located in: HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1232480833-3600853269-1034476866-1005\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\Backup\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy!App ,could they do a screenshot of what should be there and upload it please? this should be straightforward to do. thanks

That key will only exist for your user on your system.

ok, thank you... i think i'll back up my system then delete the key, reinstall the weather app to see if that'll work... fingers crossed...
